# Not able to add extra column to the list in the python

Tags: python, excel

I have two excel files, and I wanted to append those files into one. But I also want to add a work book name of excel file into a column "SourceFile".

```
df = []
for fn in xlsx_files:
    df.append(pd.read_excel(fn,sheet_name=0))
    new_column ={"SourceFile":Path(fn.name)}            
df = pd.concat([df,new_column], axis=1,ignore_index=True) 
df.to_csv(os.path.join(path_save, f"combined.csv"), index=False)
```

Error:  df = pd.concat([df,new_column], axis=1,ignore_index=True)
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

File Attached [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kdsWMgIkcEHXOYa0JaBOpEeLSqsgMIMJ?usp=sharing)

Can anyone please let me know why I am not able to add extra column with workbook name in python????

Comment: new_column is dict , and you are trying to concat it with dataframe

Comment: Read the documentation on `pd.concat()`